# Create a unique ID for a page in an ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net app with a lot of pages in it. My problem is to uniquely identify every page in my app. now the app might have pages with just the page name eg: home.aspx and can have pages with query strings eg: testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2.

what i have been thinking is since every URL in my app is unique I could use the page name + all query string params concatenated(key and value) to identify the page uniquely. 
eg : 
home.asp -> home

testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2 -> testpageq11q22

Is this the correct way to go or is there a better way to do it.

The reason I want to do this is I need to add at run time some meta data information from a database for each of the pages. The PageID then becomes my unique ID which I can then map all my meta data info in the db to.

EDIT:

the position of the query strings in the url is not important. so

testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2

testPage.aspx?q2=2&q1=1

are the same

Also there may be some cases where there is a optional query string (does not happen a lot) so something like

testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2

testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2&opt1=1

would potentially point to the same page (where the optional param gives me some kind of meta information thats is not being used to generate the content on the page)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to create an ID for the page? You can just use the URL unchanged.

That will be a few more characters, but that will hardly matter as you are already comparing strings. Also, by using it unchanged you avoid any collisions, for example between Page.aspx?ViewId=42 and PageView.aspx?Id=42.

Comment: I cant really keep the URL in its raw form as the order of the query strings is not important for to me. so for eg: 
testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2
testPage.aspx?q2=2&q1=1

are the same page to me but have different urls when I compare them. Also there may be some cases where there is a optional query string (does not happen a lot) so something like 

testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2
testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2&opt1=1
would potentially point to the same page (where the optional param gives me some kind of meta information thats is not being used to generate the content on the page)

Comment: @icecubed: Ok, then you can create a normalised URL with only the relevant parameters to identify the page. You can still use the same well known format, there is no reason to invent a new proprietary format.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a public-facing site and you have any concerns about SEO you could consider a url rewriting module such as [UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/) which would enable you to produce nicer looking Url (a bit like SO's).

So you could map

```
www.mysite.com/testpage.aspx?pageId=1
```

to the more friendly

```
www.mysite.com/1.aspx
```

or even better, if you included a nice description as a url parameter you could have Urls such as

```
www.mysite.com/testpage.aspx?pageId=1&pageTitle=something-nice
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/1/something-nice.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, it will be better if you define proper delimiters :

`testPage.aspx?q1=1&q2=2 -> testpage_q11-q22`

Here `_` is for separating page name from querystring and `-` separates a querystring parameter from another.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a hash of the url to get a slightly nicer value. Its certainly better than what you've done for the reasons others have suggested on ambiguity. It also gives you an int which is a much nicer identifier than a string. Though of course there is an exceedingly slim chance of a collision but I don't think you'll need to particularly worry about that. :)

Comment: Note that the built in GetHashCode method changes from time to time, so it's not suitable for creating a hash code that is stored in a database.

Comment: might be a trivial question but is there any standard way to do hashes in the .net library or do i have to write one myself ?